# Why does blockchain sync keep getting stuck?

Tags: blockchain

Using Windows 7 64 and GUI wallet. Have tried to sync the blockchain from scratch 4 times by deleting the data.md file. Each time the sync process gets stuck on a particular block once, always within a month or two of the current date.

On the most recent attempt, the sync got stuck on block 1217800 for 2 hours and 10 minutes before I exited the daemon.

Have tried: 
- pop-blocks (which does sometimes restart the syncing process only for it to get stuck again), 
- deleting the p2pstate.bin file, 
- syncing only via monderod or the GUI, 
- deleting the monero entries from the registry and 
- importing the raw blockchain.

My connection is fairly slow. I limited the download to my max line speed of about 200 kb/s. There seem to be a lot of peer connection errors but have yet to find any other error messages in the log. Sometimes the top block candidate changes but generally points to the longest chain.

What could be causing this problem? It's quite a nuisance as I have some XMR on an exchange which I'd like to store more safely.

Another odd thing is that the GUI crashes if I try to connect to node.moneroworld.com - there is an error message about incompatibility between the connected daemon and the GUI. As far as I understand, that node and the GUI should be compatible?

Someone suggested that the error is similar to that which occurs when trying to sync from an old version of monerod, but it's definitely 10.1 from the GUI install.

Comment: as a quick fix, try to use `node.xmrbackb.one` for your remote node. I had the same error when connecting to node.moneroworld.com

Comment: Hmm, that gives the same error: "connected daemon is not compatible with GUI. Please upgrade or connect to another daemon."

Comment: "Another odd thing is that the GUI crashes if I try to connect to node.moneroworld.com " This is because the nodes that are offered via the node.moneroworld.com address are maintained by volunteers /  random people, and they may not update their node / monero network service / monerod as often as they should.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the GUI wallet (latest version as of a few days ago). I'm stuck at 1288639.

Comment: having exactly the same issue with the same block - 1288639. Which version of the GUI are you using?

Comment: To get more information as to why the daemon is stopping syncing, exit the daemon, and restart it with --log-level 1. Once it's done downloading the next 200 blocks, it will process them, and print any error which prevents it from adding these.